# Integration on compact manifold

Tags: integration, manifolds

Integration on a nice enough manifold of a function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined
$$\int f = \sum_{ i \in I} \int_{U_i}\phi_i f$$
where $\phi_i$ is a partition of unity subordinate to the open cover $U_i$ of $M$.

The index set $I$ can be infinite in general.

If $M$ is compact (bounded), can I take $I$ to be a finite set so that the sum is a finite sum?

Comment: Yes, if $M$ is compact, you can always have a finite partition of unity subordinate to any open cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since every open cover has a finite subcover [(Heine-Borel).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Comment: Thanks, but why don't books emphasise that the sum can be finite??

Comment: I am sure some do. Also, many manifolds are not compact, but they are generally locally compact, which means that every point lies in a finite number of the open sets (this is obviously important, since infinite sums are a big pain).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I actually think that the local finiteness (global finiteness less so) is crucial for the whole machine to work, and I am sure if you read the first partitions of unity papers, it is probably emphacized.